# auto enter command at CLI?

Tags: command-line, bash

To save typing, I am thinking if it is possible to auto enter command after pause of certain number of seconds.

For example, suppose I type "ls -l" from the command line. Without typing anything else, and after 2 or 3 seconds, the command is automatically executed. Is there a way to achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That strikes me as inordinately dangerous. Suppose I type "rm -rf /" then turn my head for a couple of seconds before I type the rest of the path.

(confession: Also, I don't know how to implement it)

If you just want to introduce some delay, I could suggest:

```
later() { sleep 3; "$@"; }
```

So you type `later ls -l` and hit Enter: 3 seconds later the directory listing appears.

Or if you want  to be able to specify the delay:

```
after() { local secs=$1; shift; sleep "$secs"; "$@"; }
after 3 ls -l
```

Comment: I could probably hack something up with Expect now that I think about it, but I'm thinking about it too much.

Comment: I need this to relieve the stressfulness of right hand. I end up mapping the caps lock to enter. But thanks for the tip anyway.